# How do I prevent the insert of a unique value in multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to make sure that the insertion of the same value across multiple columns is not possible

```
Col1 | Col2 
-----|------
ABC  | DEF
XYZ  | ABC
```

The second row should be prevented because `col2` contains the value `ABC` which is also existing in the first row in `col1`

How does the `CREATE TABLE` statement look like to accomplish this?

The DBMS used is POSTGRES

Comment: Depending on your DBMS, you should create a trigger for this

Comment: what database platform? You would probably need to use a trigger in this case.

Comment: eh, shoot - I was hoping there is a way to solve this declaratively. Updated my question

Comment: Usually not a good design when you have the same type of data in multiple columns in a single table. Merge the columns (in an extra table?) into a single column and you will be fine with a unique constraint on that column.

Comment: @FrankHeikens in general I agree. In this particular instance the resulting code complexity outside the DB does not justify the normalisation of the table in to tables using a 1-m relationship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a trigger function can be a solution :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION BeforeInsertUpdate_mytable () RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE Col1 = NEW.Col1 OR Col2 = NEW.Col1 OR Col2 = NEW.Col1 OR Col2 = NEW.Col2)
  THEN RETURN NULL ;
  ELSE RETURN NEW ;
  END IF ;
END ; $$

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BeforeInsertUpdate_mytable BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF Col1, Col2 ON mytable FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION BeforeInsertUpdate_mytable () ;
```